# Differents between CURL and Guzzle,Pecl-http and Http-request2

Tags: php, curl, guzzle, pecl, http-request2

What are Differents between CURL and Guzzle,Pecl-http and Http-request2 ?
I want to connect to one site with api,I always use curl and it works for me.can I use Guzzle or Pecl-http or Http-request2 instead of curl in codeigniter or php?

Comment: If you use plain PHP I think it's a simple question of feature-set and/or preference.

Comment: If you use a framework you I'd say to generally use what the framework provides unless you understand the consequences of not doing so.

Comment: PHP’s curl is mostly a one-to-one mapping to libcurl which is very powerful although also potentially very complicated because beyond HTTP it also supports FTP, telnet, LDAP and many other protocols. The other libraries abstract away some of the lower level complexities and only support HTTP.